# Reference issue in Dotnet Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am new to dot net core , i have created a web project using asp.net core. I am getting an issue while i am adding a project reference to another project.
When i am running my project using Command Prompt , it is running successfully, but when i am running same project using Visual Studio , it is giving reference errors (ie namespace could not be found).
My project.json file have reference that is :

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0",
  "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-2",
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "platform",
    "version": "1.0.1"
  },
  "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
  "NUnit": "3.5.0",
```

"SchedulerService": { "target": "project" }
    },

Please help me .[VS issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bus6X.png)

[image]

[Reference[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQbWf.png)
[image]

Comment: Can you post full error? Also do you tried `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Yes tried , as i said it is working fine using command prompts. I am getting build errors in Visual Studio (missing assembly references) .

Comment: So post FULL error (VS should show what assembly is missing)

Comment: Please find attached images in question body.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `global.json`? Also, which version (and update) of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: As Microsoft finally shipped .NET Core tooling 1.0 on March 7, say goodbye to all the old bits and `project.json`.

Comment: i am using VS 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and my global.json contains following : {
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}